InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' in kaggle notebook
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(

    host = "localhost",
    user ="root",
    password = 'password'

)

This is the code I used and I am cannot connect to MySQL database from kaggle notebook. I am a windows 10 user.
exact error I get is 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py:509, in MySQLTCPSocket.open_connection(self)
    508     self.sock.settimeout(self._connection_timeout)
--> 509     self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
    510 except IOError as err:

ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 3
      1 import mysql.connector
----> 3 mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      4     host = "localhost",
      5     user ="root",
      6     password = 'mysqlconnection123'
      7 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py:179, in connect(*args, **kwargs)
    177     return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
    178 else:
--> 179     return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py:95, in MySQLConnection.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     92 self._pool_config_version = None
     94 if len(kwargs) > 0:
---> 95     self.connect(**kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py:716, in MySQLConnectionAbstract.connect(self, **kwargs)
    713     self.config(**kwargs)
    715 self.disconnect()
--> 716 self._open_connection()
    717 self._post_connection()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py:206, in MySQLConnection._open_connection(self)
    204 self._protocol = MySQLProtocol()
    205 self._socket = self._get_connection()
--> 206 self._socket.open_connection()
    207 self._do_handshake()
    208 self._do_auth(self._user, self._password,
    209               self._database, self._client_flags, self._charset_id,
    210               self._ssl)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py:511, in MySQLTCPSocket.open_connection(self)
    509     self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
    510 except IOError as err:
--> 511     raise errors.InterfaceError(
    512         errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
    513 except Exception as err:
    514     raise errors.OperationalError(str(err))

    InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (111 Connection     refused)

PS: I tried using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost too
I tried to connect to MySQL database from kaggle notebook and I was expecting to establish a    connection like we get in local
